# I want to use the variable declared inside an SSH session to be used locally in my shell script

Tags: shell-script, ssh, scripting, variable

Whenever I try to use the variable declared inside my SSH session it gives me blank output. Here is the code which I am trying to execute:

```
ssh -T host <<\HERE
export usage1=$(df -h |grep /nas/infa|sed s/%//g| awk '{printf("%d\n",$4)}');
echo $usage1
HERE
echo $usage1
```

I am able to get the desired output inside the SSH session, but when calling the same variable outside the SSH it gives me blank.

Comment: Maybe this can help [When ssh'ing, how can I set an environment variable on the server that changes from session to session?](http://superuser.com/questions/163167/when-sshing-how-can-i-set-an-environment-variable-on-the-server-that-changes-f). Let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the value from the remotely executed command into a variable in your local environment, it's the same as getting the value of a locally executed command into your local environment, e.g.,

```
export usage1=$(ssh -T host <<\HERE
df -h|grep /nas/infa|sed s/%//g|awk '{printf("%d\n",$4)}'
HERE
)
echo $usage1
```

Comment: Thanks,It solves the current situation, but isn't there anyway to use the variable declared inside the ssh environment locally?